# Netbeans: Launch web application into PC host name and not localhost

Tags: netbeans, tomcat7

Anyone know if there's a way to have netbeans launch the website using url
  `http://mycomputer.domain.com:8080/mywebapp` 
instead of 
  `http:// localhost :8080/mywebapp ?`

I've tried editing the server.xml and other references to localhost but it doesn't work or i've missed something.

This is in Linux Mint.